# Merge [bills] and [billing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Can the tags for [bills](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bills) (*20 questions*) and [billing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/billing) (*37 questions*) be merged?

I don't see any reason why these tags wouldn't be used interchangeably.

Comment: For what it's worth, the mods have an informal agreement to wait, as long as a week, for member feedback. If there are no objections, or just agreement, we'll handle it. Else, we'll participate in the discussion.  First, I'd ask you, which of the two would you keep? One tag must die.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I'm not sure. Maybe billing since it has more questions?

Comment: Ok. Thx for input.

Comment: I think the usage is slightly different. Bill is more of noun and also used for issues will currency notes. Billing is more processes. Maybe a tag wiki would be more apt.

Comment: If the group agrees to merge, my preference would be to keep billing and get rid of bill.

Comment: @Dheer I added an answer that conflicts with your desire. You should probably write a formal answer to allow others to vote for your desired preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put the alternate case to Nathan's answer, I propose we keep [billing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/billing).

My reasons because it's more used than [bills](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bills), which suggests that it's what our users find more natural on average.

EDIT: I've now done this. In doing so I noticed a few questions where the topic was really "paper money". I've removed the tag from those and replaced it with [cash](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cash). It's a usage specific to American English anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My preference if we merge would be to keep bills, because billing is less of a personal finance topic and more of an accounting topic. From the consumer's perspective, they are receiving a bill. They're two sides of that same coin. I prefer that we keep the focus on the consumer's perspective in that exchange.

Comment: Excellent point. If I look at it differently, in my view people think I terms of "I have a problem with billing" ... At least that is the way most questions are asked.

Comment: Fair enough, this may be a difference in the common usage on our two sides of the pond, on further reflection I'm not sure that I care either way.